# How do we write unit tests for application that uses SQLDelight?

Tags: mysql, kotlin, mockito, sqldelight, mockito-kotlin

I am writing a Kotlin JVM application that uses the SQLDelight to generate classes that needs to interact with a MySQL database.

How can I write unit tests for classes/services that use the classes that SQLDelight library generated?

For example, SQLDelight generated interfaces like these:

```
interface SomeDB : Transacter {
  val someTableQueries: SomeTableQueries

  companion object {
    val Schema: SqlDriver.Schema
      get() = SomeDB::class.schema
    operator fun invoke(driver: SqlDriver): SomeDB = SomeDB::class.newInstance(driver)
  }
}
```

```
interface SomeTableQueries : Transacter {
  fun <T : Any> querySomething(name: String, mapper: (
    id: Long,
    name: String,
    address: String
  ) -> T): Query<T>

  fun querySomething(name: String): Query<SomeTable>
}
```

And somewhere in my application, I have `myService.findAllAddressForName(name: String)`, it will do something like `someDB.someTableQueries.querySomething(name)`.

So what is the best way to unit test `myService.findAllAddressForName`?

If I need to use libraries like `Mockito` or `mockito-kotlin`, which classes should I be mocking?
Is there any better way for me to write tests for these? Thanks.

Comment: I have actually found a work around for this from the sqldelight repo. We can actually use testcontainer to achieve this. https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/blob/master/sqldelight-gradle-plugin/src/test/integration-mysql-schema/src/test/kotlin/com/squareup/sqldelight/mysql/integration/MySqlTest.kt
I will leave this question open in case someone has a better solution to this.